# jquery to access js array in other file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a js array in a separate file, array_wsd01.js, and I want jquery ui dialog code to access its elements. The file contents are:

```
var E2tw.arrayWsd01 = 
[["text01", "audio01"], 
["text02", "audio02"],      
...  
["text10", "audio10"]];
```

and the dialog code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("div#ws_dialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     resizable: false,
     draggable: false   
 });

 jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');

  jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").on("click",function(evnt) {
    jQuery("div#ws_dialog").dialog("open");
    evnt.stopPropagation();
    jQuery("div#wsd_text").text(E2tw.arrayWsd01[0][0]); 
  });     
});
```

This does not display the value of E2tw.arrayWsd01[0][0], while a string such as "Hi, there" or some such, is displayed. Firebug shows that array_wsd01.js is being loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you load the file defining the array **before** the file accessing it?

Comment: I'm using Joomla CMS. I guess the array is being loaded before I use it as I have checked this in firebug and array_wsd01.js is shown there before clicking to get the dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
var E2tw.arrayWsd01 = 
[["text01", "audio01"], 
["text02", "audio02"],      
...  
["text10", "audio10"]];
```

to

```
E2tw.arrayWsd01 = 
[["text01", "audio01"], 
["text02", "audio02"],      
...  
["text10", "audio10"]];
```

"var" isn't needed for assigning values to E2tw's properties.

And I highly recommend you use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) for checking your JavaScript code in the future. It's great for catching problems like this one :-)

Comment: I can't get the @name thing to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm already using E2tw object to namespace global variables. So to declare it again would remove all previously assigned properties. Perhaps Felix King's suggestion is the way to go? @randomducks

Comment: Sorry about that @user2176936. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Your use of "@name" seems fine to me, @user2176936. Read this for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/what-is-the-relevance-of-in-comments

Comment: OK with the invalid syntax corrected, the jquery code accesses the array, as above, when the array is declared in the same file as the jquery code. BUT when the array is declared in another file, it is not accessed by jquery. This is a problem as I want to have this array and others in the one file (for easier maintenance etc). I would have thought that as the array is a property (attribute?) of a globally declared object, it too is globally available. I'm perplexed by this.

Comment: The trouble with global variables (although they can be useful) is that they can be accessed and/or changed at any point in the code. Is there anything else that could be changing E2tw before the JQuery code has a chance to use it?

Answer (score 0):

`var E2tw.arrayWsd01 =` is invalid syntax. You should see a syntax error. As long as you have a syntax error, the code cannot be evaluated.

Assuming the file is really loaded, changing it to

```
var E2tw = {
    arrayWsd01: [["text01", "audio01"], ...]
};
```

should fix the problem. This declares an object with property `arrayWsd01`, which can be accessed as `E2tw.arrayWsd01` (like you already do). Of course if that's the only property, it doesn't make sense to use an object at all.

Comment: I'm already using E2tw object to namespace global variables. So I can assign arrayWsd01 to E2tw as you suggest or would that overwrite previously assigned properties? @Felix Kling

Comment: Then maybe it should be `E2tw.arrayWsd01`, but you said in another comment that it doesn't work for you either. In that case we don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

your file should be like this

A.js

```
 var E2tw = [["text01", "audio01"],["text02", "audio02"],      
  ...  
  ["text10", "audio10"]];
```

To use in Other file

B.html

```
<script src="A.js"></script>
<script>
  function(){
     alert(E2tw[0]);//you can use directly as variable.
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @ rajesh kakwat  do you mean that there should be no CRs or white spaces between the array elements?

Comment: @user2176936 no, you just have to include file is script src and include it before you use it.just check variable naming convention.